# Is there a way to group by logical comparison of two columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a a dataframe with the following structure:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1152 entries, 0 to 143
Data columns:
cuepos             1152  non-null values
response           1152  non-null values
soa                1152  non-null values
targetpos          1152  non-null values
testorientation    1152  non-null values
dtypes: float64(3), int64(2)
```

The `cuepos` column and the `targetpos` column both contain integer values of either `1` or `2`.

I would like to group this data by **congruency** between `cuepos` and `targetpos`.  In other words, I would like to produce two groups, one for rows in which `cuepos == targetpos` and another group for which `cuepos != targetpos`.

I can't seem to figure out how I might do this.  I looked at using grouping functions, but these seem only to act on a single column... or am I mistaken?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!
Blz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note, if you goal is to do group computations, you *can* do

```
df.groupby(df.col1 == df.col2).apply(f)
```

and the result will be keyed by True/False.

Answer (score 4):

you can group by multiple columns:

> df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).apply(lambda x: x['col1'] == x['col2'], axis=1)

you can also use a mask:

> df[df.col1==df.col2]

Comment: Maybe I'm not quite grasping the `groupby().apply()` call, but I get the impression that this doesn't do what I'd like.  Specifically, doing `groupby(['col1', 'col2'])` gives me *four* groups, defined as tuples structured as `(col1_value, col2_value)`.  I'd like to have *two* groups, labelled in such a way as to convey whether or not the value of column 1 is the same as the value of column 2.  Does that make sense?  Using a mask is my fallback option, at this point =)

Comment: df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).apply(lambda x: x['col1'] == x['col2'], axis=1) will groupy col1, col2 and you will have another column with True if col1 equals col2 otherwise False

Comment: Yeah that seems like an acceptable solution.  I should have thought of that ^^!